# VC++ 6.0 Generated .TLH from COM DLL Results in Errors

Tags: c++, .net, dll, typelib

The problem is, I have a DLL and TLB that I created in C#.NET, made it COM visible and wanted to expose the functions to my MFC C++ project - I made a test class first and it worked correctly, and didn't get any errors from C++'s generated tlh. Now the actual DLL I want to use is giving me the following compilation errors:

```
error C2059: syntax error : '<'
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
error C2059: syntax error : '<'
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
error C2059: syntax error : '<'
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

From the following C++ generated tlh file:

```
//
// Type library items
//

struct __declspec(uuid("d6b19eb0-56bf-3c30-9f3a-ebafca303996"))
Class1;
// [ default ] interface _Class1
// interface _Object

struct __declspec(uuid("a7e7ae20-5fb3-3c3f-a9fb-1fac0128dea1"))
IProtracReader : IDispatch
{}

struct TagReadEvent
{
__int64 <Index>k__BackingField;     <<< These three lines are where the errors are.
__int64 <TagID>k__BackingField;
DATE <EventMoment>k__BackingField;
};
```

Does anyone know why the compiler is generating this file thats giving me errors? Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are fields that are generated by the C# compiler when you use automatic properties.  Like:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class TagReadEvent {
    public long Index { get; set; }
    // etc...
}
```

You ought to go back and fix the C# code.  Also use interfaces and keep classes/structs as [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)] so that none of the implementation is exposed.  The COM way.  If you can't then you can use the *exclude* attribute in the #import directive to skip the troublemakers.  Like:

```
#import "something.dll" exclude("TagReadEvent")
```

The *rename* attribute can fix it too.